# Service Now API in Logic Apps

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am trying to use the Logic Apps ServiceNow connector.

I have got most of the fields from the request, the last item which i need are the variables text inputs in ServiceNow. I have identified that i can get the information from **sc_item_option_mtom** table and **sc_item_option** respectively.

The output of **sc_item_option_mtom** looks like below -

```
     "result": [
                    {
                        "sys_id": "00d1ce4adb75c4144664a27314961454",
                        "sys_updated_by": "Bot.One",
                        "sys_created_on": "04/01/2020 12:23:21",
                        "sys_mod_count": "0",
                        "request_item": {
                            "display_value": "RITM0032344",
                            "link": "https://dev.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sc_req_item/ggd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195f"
                        },
                        "sc_item_option": {
                            "display_value": "ggd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195e",
                            "link": "https://dev.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sc_item_option/ggd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195e"
                        },
                        "sys_updated_on": "04/01/2020 12:23:21",
                        "sys_tags": "",
                        "sys_created_by": "Bot.One"
                    }
                  ]
```

I need to get **sc_item_option.display_value** to be used as a input into the sc_item_option table. When i do this in Logic apps, it create a for each loop(which is correct), but the option i get is a **Dependent Item**

[image: Logic apps setup]

When i run the logic app the Dependent Item looks like  -

```
"sys_id={\"display_value\":\"ggd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195e\",\"link\":\"https://dev.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sc_item_option/ggd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195e"}"},
```

I've tried editing the code to just get the display_value. Things i have tried are -

- sc_item_option.display_value.[0]
- sc_item_option.display_value[0]
- sc_item_option.[0]
- sc_item_option[0]

Nothing seems to work and not give me the value which is in display_value.

Can someone help me and tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Full List Records file -

```
  "result": [
            {
                "sys_id": "00d1ce4adb75c4144664a27314961454",
                "sys_updated_by": "Bot.One",
                "sys_created_on": "04/01/2020 12:23:21",
                "sys_mod_count": "0",
                "request_item": {
                    "display_value": "RITM0032344",
                    "link": "https://yarratramsau.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sc_req_item/ggd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195f"
                },
                "sc_item_option": {
                    "display_value": "ccd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195e",
                    "link": "https://yarratramsau.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sc_item_option/ggd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195e"
                },
                "sys_updated_on": "04/01/2020 12:23:21",
                "sys_tags": "",
                "sys_created_by": "Bot.One"
            },
            {
                "sys_id": "0cd1ce4adb75c4144664a27314961960",
                "sys_updated_by": "Bot.One",
                "sys_created_on": "04/01/2020 12:23:21",
                "sys_mod_count": "0",
                "request_item": {
                    "display_value": "RITM0032344",
                    "link": "https://yarratramsau.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sc_req_item/ggd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195f"
                },
                "sc_item_option": {
                    "display_value": "4fd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195e",
                    "link": "https://yarratramsau.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sc_item_option/4fd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195e"
                },
                "sys_updated_on": "04/01/2020 12:23:21",
                "sys_tags": "",
                "sys_created_by": "Bot.One"
            },
            {
                "sys_id": "c0d1ce4adb75c4144664a27314961960",
                "sys_updated_by": "Bot.One",
                "sys_created_on": "04/01/2020 12:23:21",
                "sys_mod_count": "0",
                "request_item": {
                    "display_value": "RITM0032344",
                    "link": "https://yarratramsau.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sc_req_item/ggd1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195f"
                },
                "sc_item_option": {
                    "display_value": "40a1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195f",
                    "link": "https://yarratramsau.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sc_item_option/40a1ce4adb75c4144664a2731496195f"
                },
                "sys_updated_on": "04/01/2020 12:23:21",
                "sys_tags": "",
                "sys_created_by": "Bot.One"
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this expression below to fill in the "Query" box of "**List Records**" action:

```
body('Item_Options(sc_item_option_mtom)')[0].sc_item_option.display_value
```

By the way, it seems there is just one item in the result of "**sc_item_option_mtom**", so you do not need to use the "For each" loop(I know it would create the "For each" automatically), but you just need to create the "**List Records**" action and input the expression above to the "Query" box of the action directly(without "For each" loop).

**Update:**

For the update of your requirements, you can refer to the solution below:

Input the expression below to the "Query" box of "List Records" action:

```
items('For_each').sc_item_option.display_value
```

[image]

So in the "Query" box of "List Records" action, it should be like:

[image]

Comment: I tired doing sys_id=body('Item_Options(sc_item_option_mtom)')[0].sc_item_option.display_value - it didn't really work.

Comment: Hi @Warlord, could you please provide a screenshot of the "List Records" in your logic app ?

Comment: I have added the full output of the result and to answer your question earlier, the sc_item_option does repeats for a single item, because there couple be multiple fields. Therefore there is a foreach loop. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Warlord, sorry, I mean want a screenshot of the "List Records" action. But according to the json data of "List Records" you provided, I saw there is more than one items in the json data. So please wait a moment, I will modify my answer later to match your requirements. And still ask for a screenshot of the "List Record" action in your logic app(not the json data)

Comment: Hi @Warlord, I have updated my answer, please refer to the solution I updated. If still have any problems, please free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Hury Shen -  i was able to use the code snippet and make it work.